# UWP ListView only displays data sometimes

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

My data from an ObservableCollection only sometimes displays on my ListView. If I restart the app, the data displays fine. Sometimes when I navigate away from the page and go back, the data will sometimes display and other times not. It seems to be random.

Here is my XAML code:

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="2" Margin="0,42,0,0">
            <Grid>
                <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind collection, Mode=OneWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsItemClickEnabled="True" SelectionChanged="MySelectionChanged" Visibility="Visible">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:ObjectName">
                                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Data0, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
                <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind collection, Mode=OneWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="375,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" SelectionMode="None" Visibility="Visible">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:ObjectName">
                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Data1, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

I tried doing a Debug.WriteLine() on all the data that should be displayed, and the debug output successfully prints it every time. There's only a problem when it comes to displaying this data on the ListView.

**EDIT:** Here's the corresponding xaml.cs code:

```
private ObservableCollection<ObjectName> collection;
    private List<ObjectName> sorted;
    private ObjectName clicked = new ObjectName();

    public MainPage()
    {            
        GetSave();
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }        

    private async void GetSave()
    {
        DataStorage ds = new DataStorage();
        await ds.DeserializeObjectAsync();
        collection = ds.ObjectName;
        if (collection != null)
        {
            sorted = new List<ObjectName>(collection);
            sorted.Sort((x, y) => string.Compare(x.Data0, y.Data0));
            collection = new ObservableCollection<ObjectName>(sorted);
        }
    }
```

I tried InitializeComponent() before and after the logic, and it gives the same result.

Comment: Could you please add more code about your 'collection'? How does it actually look like? How/when do you instantiate/initialize it?

Comment: I have edited the requested code into the OP. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the xaml.cs code you provided, the problem looks like this:

First, you are not awaiting an async call.

Second, you are replacing the ObservableCollection.

The solution:

1. Don't call async code from your page's constructor. Async calls are
   called async for a reason and trying to 'hide' their true nature by
   omitting the await keyword when calling them won't work. Change GetSave()'s
   return value to Task, override the OnNavigatedTo() method (read more
   about it in it's documentation) of MainPage and await GetSave()
   inside that. This alone won't solve your problem though.
2. Never replace an ObservableCollection. I remember banging my head on the
   wall multiple times because of this. What you need to understand is
   that when you are binding to an object in XAML, a dedicated Binding
   object is created that links the source (in your case, the
   ObservableCollection) and the target (the ListView) together. In
   your code, initially 'collection' is set to null. When your MainPage
   is created, the Binding object is created as well and it binds that
   null value to your ListViews' Source property. Later, when your
   async initialzation code is finished, you replace that null value
   with an actual ObservableCollection, but the ListViews are not
   notified about that, they are only looking for changes in the
   collection's items that they are bound to, they are not prepared for
   handling the situation when the collection itself is swapped
   under them. So what you can do to fix this problem is: only create
   your ObservableCollection instance in MainPage's constructor (or at
   declaration - matter of taste in this case) and in GetSave() first
   call collection.Clear() and then add your items to it with
   collection.Add().

What currently happening in your code is that in some cases you are replacing the ObservableCollection before the Binding object is created and sometimes after that, so that's why it looks like you app's behavior is totally random - because actually it is. :) By adding the modifications I suggested above, you'll make sure that the Binding object is bound to the ObservableCollection you created in the constructor (empty at the time of the binding), and then you are initializing that collection after MainPage is already loaded, so your ListViews are getting notified about the changes.

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked perfectly. I appreciate the detailed explanation! :)

Comment: You are welcome! I am glad that I was able to help. :)